# ¿porque recibo la señal SIGABRT al acabar una funcion void en c?

Tags: c, linux, socket

Estoy haciendo un progama con sockets en linux y tanto en el servidor como en el cliente recibo la señal SIGABRT al acabar una de mis funciones. No entiendo que puede causar esto y os agradecería mucho si alguien pudiese explicarmelo. Esta es la funcion que da error al acabar. (con el debugger he comprobado que la ultima linea se ejecuta sin problema y que no llega a ejecutarse la linea siguiente a donde uso la funcion)

```
void programaReceptor(int fd)
{
    int modo = 1 ;
    long id;
    char respuesta,envio;
    char nombre[40];

    if (send(fd,&modo,sizeof(int),0) == -1){ //manda un 1 para indicar su modo
        printf("Error al mandar el modo \n");
        close(fd);
        return;
    }

    if (recv(fd,&id,sizeof(long ),0) == -1){ //recibe un int que corresponde a su id
        printf("Error al recibir la id.\n");
        close(fd);
        return;
    }


    while(respuesta != 'S')
    {
        system("clear");
        printf("Tu ID es %d. \nEsperando Conexiones....",id);

        if (recv(fd,nombre,41,0) == -1){ //recibe el nombre del que intenta mandar un archivo
            printf("Error el nombre.\n");
            close(fd);
            return;
        }

        respuesta = acceptarConexion(nombre);

        if(respuesta == 'S')
        {
            envio = 1;
            if (send(fd,&envio,sizeof(char ),0) == -1){ //si la accepta manda un 1
                printf("Error al mandar el modo \n");
                close(fd);
                return;
            }
        }else
        {
            envio = 0;
            if (send(fd,&envio,sizeof(char ),0) == -1){ // si no accepta manda un 0
                printf("Error al mandar el modo \n");
                close(fd);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    recibirArchivo(fd);
    //while
    //recibe char[40] nombre del emisor
    //manda char '1' o '0' segun si accepta o rechaza la conexion
    //Acaba while

    //recibe el archivo
}
```

Esto es lo que se me imprime por consola cuando falla el programa:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Comment: Entiendo que el programa está siendo interrumpido. Por lo que tienes que preocuparte es por el mensaje de error **stack smashing detected**.

Comment: @Mateo el problema es que al buscar en internet he encontrado que este sale principalmente por culpa de escribir en posiciones de arrays que no existen o punteros que no llevan a ningún sitio pero a mi me salta justo al acabar la funcion y no entiendo pq

Comment: ¿Será por la instrucción `recv(fd,nombre,41,0)`? A simple vista es lo único que está escribiendo fuera. Ya que el arreglo solo tiene lugar para 40 caracteres. También es posible que ocurra en la función que no está cargada `recibirArchivo`.

Comment: @Mateo muchísimas gracias d vdd. El problema era el recv que había puesto que recibiera 41 para incluir también el \0 pero se ve q no se podía hacer eso. Pon una respuesta para que pueda votarla y ponerle el verificado si quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error **stack smashing detected** significa que estás escribiendo en un sector de memoria que no deberías.

Es posible que la instrucción `recv(fd,nombre,41,0)` este causando el error. Ya que tiene espacio para 40 caracteres pero en el parámetro indicas que puede usar 41.

---

Parece que confundiste los arreglos con los literales de string.

Ambos tienen longitud fija, la diferencia es que los arreglos tienen el tamaño que tú les des. En este caso `nombre` solo puede almacenar 40 caracteres.

Mientras que un literal, por ejemplo `"Hola"` a simple vista está compuesto por 4 caracteres pero en realidad son 5, ya que se agrega un caracter nulo (0) para identificar el final de la misma.